# Multiple REGEXEXTRACT in Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a line of text in Google sheets which contains several kinds of brands.

Text in cell B2:
[brand]weber[brand] [category]spring[category] [brand]bosch[brand]

Result in column D2 must be:
weber bosch

I'm trying to use this formula:
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2; "[brand](.*?)[brand]")

But it finds only the first [brand]....[brand]
is there anyone who can help with how I find all [brand]....[brand] in a text in a text and write the text in between [brand]....[brand]

Any help appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, is the number of brands fixed (always 2 ?) or is that number variable?

Comment: Also, I notice spaces between the different tags. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are spaces between the different tags (as in your example) you can try in B2

```
=textjoin(", ", 1, ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(split(regexreplace(A2, "\](\s)\[","]_["), "_"), "\[brand\](.*?)\[brand\]"))))
```

If not, and the number of brands is fixed (eg. 2 brands) you can try

```
=regexextract(A2, rept(".*\[brand\](.*?)\[brand\]", 2))
```

If the number of brands present in the string is variable, you can calculate the number of brands present and use that as the second parameter in the rept() function.

```
=regexextract(A2, rept(".*\[brand\](.*?)\[brand\]", (len(A2)-len(substitute(A2, "[brand]",)))/(2*LEN("[brand]"))))
```

If you need the output to be in a single cell (as in the first formula) you can wrap join(", ", ...) around the last two formulas.

Hope that helps?

Comment: It looks very promising! :)
I need the output to be in a single cell yes, but will you try to put  join(", ", ...) round, since I get an error when I do it.

Comment: Note that your locale may require the use of semi-colons instead of comma's.

Comment: This one works fine, but..
=textjoin(", ", 1, ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(split(A2, " "), ".*\[brand\](.*?)\[brand\]"))))

If the text in cell B2 has 2 words like: [brand]hugo boss[brand] then it does not work?

Comment: @Smedegaard: I updated the first formula to =textjoin(", ", 1, ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(split(regexreplace(A2, "\](\s)\[","]_["), "_"), "\[brand\](.*?)\[brand\]")))). See if that works for brands with spaces?

Comment: I get an error in the formula. I created a test sheet, will you see if you can fix it there?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nF0ElBxWRIXoIGChvCfXvgLq_9ne1dVMvsLr9tZx2lA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Strange: some characters are missing from my previous post. The forumula in my edited post is correct, but your locale requires the use of semi-colons. Here's a copy of your sheet with working formula: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xv1L7wJHDcgyyLE3os2ImAoeTkY7jsVskAnAhCnB9Wc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Glad to hear it works @Smedegaard ! Since you are new here, you also may want to check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Regards,JPV.